# How to include things like domain name, site title into your code?

Tags: php

How to include things like domain name, site title into your code, which you need to be able to access throughout most of your code? Should you just make constants for them or a class with these things as properties or something else? Or should this be passed via function/method parameters?

Comment: The domain name is stored in the environment variable: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. What is site title?

Comment: what do you mean like [server variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example with all the existing PHP Server variables: http://www.w3resource.com/php/super-variables/$_SERVER.php

e.g.

```
["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(9) "localhost"
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the domain name i.e your URL php has few variables called as Global Variables.
Please refer the URL http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php